# Why is my stable_baselines3 model with Cartpole gym environment improving mean episode reward with sutton_barto_reward?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

When I run this code, I see the episode length mean continually increase (like a good model should), while the episode mean reward stays the same at -1, which is how the sutton_barto_reward system works.

```
import gymnasium
from cartpole import CartPoleEnv
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.ppo.policies import MlpPolicy

env = CartPoleEnv(sutton_barto_reward=True)

model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, gamma=1, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=30000)
```

However, I don't understand why this works, since there does not seem to be any discount rate used in the Cartpole code in gymnasium's GitHub documentation. Shouldn't there be no improvement at all in the episode length mean, since the episode's cumulative reward is always the same?